# How to convert xml element to value?

Tags: xslt, groovy

I'm new to xslt, I have following requirement to convert XML element to value.

input XML

```
<Record>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <LastName>Doe</LastName>
</Record>
```

Output should be

```
<Record>
  <Tag>FirstName</Tag>
  <Value>John</Value>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Tag>LastName</Tag>
  <Value>Doe</Value>
</Record>
```

The code i'm using now, is folowing

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0" >
    <xsl:output method = "xml" />
    <xsl:template match = "//Record/*">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<]]></xsl:text><xsl:text >Tag</xsl:text><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">></xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select = "name()" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<]]></xsl:text><xsl:text >/Tag</xsl:text><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">></xsl:text>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<]]></xsl:text><xsl:text >Value</xsl:text><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">></xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select = "namespace-uri()" />
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<]]></xsl:text><xsl:text >/Value</xsl:text><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">></xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and output I'm getting is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Tag>FirstName</Tag><Value></Value>John  
<Tag>LastName</Tag><Value></Value>Doe
```

Please help me, how to achieve this, i tried name(), LocalName() of xslt, but not sure how to create the output structure.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Your two `<Record>` nodes in the output should be enclosed into a unique root node, as `<Records>` for example, in order to get a well formed XML document as result. Or more likely, you will want only one `<Record>` node with two `<Field>` nodes (for example) in it, enclosing each a pair of `<Tag>` and `<Value>` nodes.

Comment: I updated my code, and Pierre, you are right, ultimately the entire xml will go withing <Records> node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to output markup as escaped text. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Record">
    <Records>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
    </Records>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <Record>
        <Tag>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        </Tag>
        <Value>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </Value>
    </Record>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```